# Annoying access problem on /var/log/nginx

Tags: permissions, php, nginx, ownership, logrotate

On my system (14.04), I'm not using `www-data` as the owner of *nginx* and *php-fpm*, using `web` instead.

<sup>(for the curious: 1. because www-data is a ugly name, 2. for not using a user that everyone knows is the default).</sup>

AFAIK, all necessary settings have been changed accordingly (while www-data is still a valid user in /etc/passwd)

- nginx setup
- php-fpm setup
- `/etc/logrotate.d/nginx` doing `create 0640 web adm` instead

Doing a `grep -r www-data /etc/*` shows only some lines for the user files (passwd, shadow...) - nothing else.

Yet, every now and then, for some reason, access to `/var/log/nginx` is back to `www-data:adm`.

It seems to be related to logrotate though its settings have been changed, and the *grep* shows no relevant match.

Is there something else to look to ensure `/var/log/nginx` will be set to `web:adm` for good, and not set back to `www-data:adm` some time in the future?

Comment: You could use `inotifywait` (`sudo apt-get install inotify-tools`; man inotifywait`) to see when the ownership changes. I ran `inotifywatch` on a test directory, did a `chown`, and `inotifywait` said "`tmp/inotify/ ATTRIB file`".

Comment: Use `dpkg  -l nginx\*` and `dpkg -l php-fpm\*` to get a list of all the packages you have installed for this problem. For each of these packages, do `dpkg -L <packagename>`. combine these to get a list of all the files and directories in the packages. `grep` these for `www-data`

Comment: Thanks, inotifywait may be an option. The grep however, you mean grep of the binary files?

Comment: Yes. Gnu grep will say "binary file foo matches". I mean grep ALL the files, binaries, scripts, documentation, libraries,...

Comment: Indeed the grep would have pointed to the postint, as per the answer of @oerdnj - was the right track!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dpkg-statoverride` to change the user and group for `/var/log/nginx` as the change is most likely happen in `postinst` script on every package update.

Comment: That's a good hint! Would you know the command to show what ownership is set for a given package / file?

Comment: Run `dpkg-statoverride --help` or `man dpkg-statoverride`, I am only on my phone whole time. (It should be something like `dpkg-statoverride --list /var/log/nginx`, but that's just a guess...)

Comment: Also you can grep `/var/lib/dpkg/info/` directory for suspects...

Comment: Bingo! nginx-common.postint is the cultprit, `chown www-data:adm $logdir` and as you advised `dpkg-statoverride` is *the* command, as postint does `if ! dpkg-statoverride --list "$logdir"` beforehand. Great answer, thanks.